# Serialization through the Django Rest Framework - how to deserialize?

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have an array of the objects and then try to serialize it using the following statement:

```
serializer = MovieWithDescriptionSerializer(movies, many=True) 
data = serializer.data
```

The class and the serializer are as below:

```
class MovieWithDescription(object):
    id = 0
    name = ''
    description = ''
    rating = ''
    year = 0

    def __init__(self, uid, name, description):
        self.id = uid
        self.name = name
        self.description = description


class MovieWithDescriptionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MovieWithDescription
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description')

    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    description = serializers.StringRelatedField()
```

The data is saved to session:

```
request.session['movies'] = data
```

And read on the other page:

```
movies = request.session['movies']
```

However when I tried to deserialize it I learned that the movies variable contains list. So it looks like I don't need to deserialize and just need to iterate through the list to process the data. What I'm doing wrong with this serialization? Is there any more simple way to serialize data than to use Django Rest Framework?

Comment: What's your expected result when you do `request.session['movies']`? Right now, it will be a list of python dicts from what I see. Do you want int in a format such that you can pass it to the serializer again? Is that the goal?

Comment: Actually the result now is fine because exactly what I need is to iterate through this list and get some data. However I don't fully understand how it works. As I use JSON.NET to serialize something in C# it works the following way: List->Serialize->JSON string and if I want get my objects back in the list I need to do: JSON->Deserialize->List How does it works in DjangoRestSerializer?

Comment: So in Django Rest Framework this is what happens:
Python Object -> Serializer -> Python Native Data Types -> Render Class (JSON/XML) -> JSON.
The conversion from python primitive types to Json is done inside `return Response(serializer.data)`
See: `rendered_content` inside `rest_framework.response`

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question from the comments section; also to clarify for whoever is migrating from a Java environment:

In Django Rest Framework; Serialization happens as follows:

Python Object --> serializer.data ==> Python Native Types --> Renderer Class ==> JSON

`serializer.data` is constructed by calling `to_representation` on each of the fields declared on the Serializer.

```
@property
def data(self):
    ...
    if not hasattr(self, '_data'):
        if self.instance is not None and not getattr(self, '_errors', None):
            self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
        elif hasattr(self, '_validated_data') and not getattr(self, '_errors', None):
            self._data = self.to_representation(self.validated_data)
        else:
            self._data = self.get_initial()
    return self._data
```

To representation is supposed to take an object instance and return a dict of primitive types:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    """
    Object instance -> Dict of primitive datatypes.
    """
    ...
```

So if serializer.data does not render to JSON, where does this magic happen?

It happens inside the `Response` object. When you construct a `Response` object with the `data` attribute (data here is a dict of primitive or a list of dict of primitives), the `rendered_content` method then defines how the data is rendered, sets the appropriate `Content-Type` headers, and so on.

```
@property
def rendered_content(self):
    renderer = getattr(self, 'accepted_renderer', None)
    accepted_media_type = getattr(self, 'accepted_media_type', None)
    context = getattr(self, 'renderer_context', None)

    assert renderer, ".accepted_renderer not set on Response"
    assert accepted_media_type, ".accepted_media_type not set on Response"
    assert context is not None, ".renderer_context not set on Response"
    context['response'] = self

    media_type = renderer.media_type
    charset = renderer.charset
    content_type = self.content_type

    if content_type is None and charset is not None:
        content_type = "{0}; charset={1}".format(media_type, charset)
    elif content_type is None:
        content_type = media_type
    self['Content-Type'] = content_type

    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
    if isinstance(ret, six.text_type):
        assert charset, (
            'renderer returned unicode, and did not specify '
            'a charset value.'
        )
        return bytes(ret.encode(charset))

    if not ret:
        del self['Content-Type']

    return ret
```

This allows you to do something neat; you can define a single Django Rest Framework View, that can render XML, JSON, and many more -> you can find them under `rest_framework.renderers`.

For example, you can define an `APIView` that supports multiple render formats based on the query parameter (`?format=json`, `?format=xml`, `?format=csv`) as follows:

```
class ExampleAPIView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, XMLRenderer, CSVRenderer)
    ...
```

XML and CSV require additional package installations. Read more here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#xml